# MariaDb Galera Cluster error with libgalera_smm.so config

Tags: database-replication, mariadb, galera

I am trying to setup a Galera cluster between three MariaDb nodes. However, i cannot even pass through the config of the first node. When i do the config and try to restart MariaDB, it seems to be having a problem with lines starting with wsrep_ in the config file (/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf).

I am running CentOs-6.5 64-Bits, and the MariaDB version is 10.0x.

The following is a complete config in the /etc/my.cnf.d/server/cnf file:

```
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#The lines below are the ones causing the error and will not let MariaDb start
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.1.20,192.168.1.30
wsrep_cluster_name='cluster1'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.1.10'
wsrep_node_name='db1'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=root:password
```

How can i get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any major problem in your config file,but sometimes small things results into such problem.
Under the 'wsrep_cluster_address' give the IPs of all the three nodes and also put the entire thing in ''.After doing so,it should look like
wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://192.168.1.20,192.168.1.30,192.168.1.xx'
Hope this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should be under a section named [mariadb] in your server.cnf file.

Did you provide your whole server.cnf file? If yes, please try to add [mariadb] section header before your configuation.

Comment: In MariaDB Galera cluster, the section is manditory under [galera] not [mariadb] and i have used it with success before. I found out that the problem is the wsrep_cluster_address. For some reason, it does not like that line and i am not sure how to get around this issue. Any help would be appreciated